# Why is the scar left on Kat even after she passed through the airport turnstile?

Tags: tenet

At the end of the movie, Kat show his scar to Sator:

[image]

Why is the scar left on Kat even after she was entered into airport turnstile?

Comment: She was shot in forward time, so her injury was 'normal'. It's just that since she got shot by an inverted bullet, the radiation poisoning was the reason why she needed to go through the turnstile.

Comment: @Möoz: What radiation poisoning?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the scar left on Kat even after she was entered into airport turnstile?

The turnstile merely inverts your "entropy", or your flow through time - it doesn't heal you or undoes the effects of what had happened to you, in your own timeline, before the inversion. So, Kat was shot, and the wound leaves a scar.